# I search how to match with my last character

Tags: powershell

I'm on PowerShell and i need to match my last character of my variable:

***My example is not to get user***

```
$Myobject = Get-Something -Filter 'Name -like "T*"'
```

When I write `$Myobject` I have this:

```
Ta
Taaa
Tb
Tbaa
Tc
Tcaa
```

I'm trying to match to have only:

```
Ta
Tb
Tc
```

So I have try this:

```
$MyObject | Where-Object{ ($_.Name -match '^T[a-c]$')} | Select-Object Name
```

The only result i have with different type of command is the first result and it's impossible to find on the web "How to match the last character".

Thank you for your help.

Best regards

Comment: What is the result of running the code? What items does it match?

Comment: You've seemingly done the work already. If you want to match a final character of a string to a specific character set, then use `$object -match '[a-c]$'` for matching a final `a`, `b`, or `c`. If you only want two-letter matches, then use `$object -match '^[a-z]{2}$'`. Otherwise, we need more information.

Comment: One of the fastest ways to work with RegEx, and figure out what works and doesn't work, is to go to a website such as https://regex101.com/ do some experimenting.  If you put your `^T[a-c]$` in the top, and your test strings in box below that, it will show you on the right side the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only trying to do the wildcard for the one character following the string you've specified, the easiest option (which sticks with your existing code format) is to use ? rather than *.

Using a * catches everything after the specified string, while ? only catches a single string. As a very rough example :

```
$foo = @("Ta","Taaaa","Tbaaa","Tb")
$foo | where-object {$_ -like "T?"}
```

you'll see it only returns Ta and Tb like you're after.

So in your example above it would be :

```
$Myobject = Get-Something -Filter 'Name -like "T?"'
```